# (Xamarin Studio) Storyboard UIViewController overridden methods not getting called

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, storyboard

I want to push a new UIViewController, but the new viewcontroller not calling any overridden method like ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear, AwakeFromNib,.. only the contructor get called...
I am using storyboard and pushing the controller with the following code:

```
ContentViewController cvc = AppDelegate.storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("ContentViewController") as ContentViewController;
NavigationController.PushViewController (cvc, true);
```

Any ideas? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning all, closing Xamarin Studio and rebuilding solved the problem, thanx anyway.